# What solid state memory do you use?

Tags: memory, ssd, storage, recommendations, flash

I was wondering about what brands on memory people were using?  I have always stuck to Sandisk Extreme III and have had no problems, but I have heard some horror stories and wondered what every one else uses.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Sandisk Ultra II CF cards for some time now and been very happy with them.  Never had a read/write fault in the 3 or 4 years I've had them.  Use them for both a stereo audio recorder and for a Canon DSLR.  Put thousands of hours of audio, 10,000+ pictures on each of the ones I have and never had an issue.